# Annoying bugcheck - prevents laptop from going to sleep

Tags: windows-8, macbook-pro, bsod

I have an Apple MacBook Pro Mid 2012 (i7 3720 QM, 8 GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GT650M) and running Windows 8 Pro 64-bit via Bootcamp. Over the past couple of days, it doesn't sleep when I close the lid (it stays on) and on opening the lid, it shuts down! I was digging through the Event Viewer and found this error:

*The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xfffffa800761c6b0, 0xfffff803304187f0, 0xfffffa8011aa7870). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 042813-33109-01.*

Some logs are here: http://sdrv.ms/10LGQ4N

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows crashes because of the [DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) bugcheck. WinDbg tells me that the **MS PPP Framing Driver (ndiswan.sys)** causes the issue.

Which Wide Area Network do you use?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. Do you mean how I connect to the Internet?

Comment: yes. How do you connect to the www?

Comment: Nailed the problem. So, what happened was I upgraded Connectify from v3.7 to v5. This v5 installed a new network driver which was screwing up my sleep and hibernate. I have downgraded to v3.7 and all is fine again. I'm going to resolve this with Connectify Support. Thanks for giving me the lead!